# How the get the total height of the div which is appended many DIV by jquery?

Tags: jquery

I used jquery to appended many DIVs to #main, and the height of #main is auto, then I want to get the total height of #main, but the height is always 0, so how can I get the total height of #main after insert many DIV by jquery? Is there possible to create a DEMO for me? Thanks so much in advanced!

Comment: give us something, please. How did you try to get height?

Comment: did you try `$('<selecor>').outerHeight(true)` to get the total height

Comment: Also create a demo to illustrate your problem using http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Option 1) Don't bother calculating the height of #main if you know the heights of the divs, just add the heights of the divs + their top and bottom paddings + their top and bottom margins.

Option 2) Give your #main a background color and be sure it is actually expanding to the size of the inserted divs.  If it isn't, then you can retrieve the height easily, you just needed to figure out why it isn't expanding.  Perhaps you have floated the inner divs without clearing anything or using overflow properties?

Option 3) Are you checking the height before the divs are fully created?  Try delaying the retrieval of the height to see if it is checking before the divs load.

Answer (score 0):

Check this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/HJ4Gc/1/

```
$('#add').on('click',function(){
    $('#main').append('<div>I used jquery to appended many DIVs to #main, and the height of #main is auto, then I want to get the total height of #main, but the height is always 0, so how can I get the total height of #main after insert many DIV by jquery? Is there possible to create a DEMO for me? Thanks so much in advanced!<br /></div>');
});
$('#getHeight').on('click',function(){
    alert($('#main').height());
});
```